# Custom print function has undesired behaviour

Tags: c, x86, i386

I'm making my own x86 OS using the i386-elf cross-compiler and linker and nasm to compile asm files. The OS itself runs with qemu. That being said, I made a custom print function but ran into a problem. Every time I access memory (either through the [] operator or by dereferencing a pointer) and call my print function afterwards, it leaves 8 blank spaces and then prints normally.
Print code:

```
void printv(char *str, ...)
{
    unsigned int tmp_cursor = get_cursor_position();
    cursor_position.x = (unsigned short)(tmp_cursor >> 16);
    cursor_position.y = (unsigned short)tmp_cursor;
    char buffer[12];

    va_list list_ptr;
    va_start(list_ptr, str);
    
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (char *ptr = str; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++)
    {    
        switch (*ptr)
        {
        case '%':
            cursor_position.y += (cursor_position.x + i) / 80;
            cursor_position.x = (cursor_position.x + i) % 80;            
            update_cursor(cursor_position.x, cursor_position.y);
            i = 0;
            switch (*(ptr + 1))
            {
            case 'c':
                buffer[0] = (char)va_arg(list_ptr, int);
                buffer[1] = '\0';
                printv(buffer);
                ptr++;
                break;
            case 's':
                printv(va_arg(list_ptr, char *));
                ptr++;
                break;
            case 'i':
            case 'd':                
                int_to_str(va_arg(list_ptr, int), buffer, 10);
                printv(buffer);
                ptr++;
                break;         
            default:     
                *(char*)(0xb8000 + (cursor_position.x + i + cursor_position.y * 80) * 2) = *ptr;
                i++;       
                break;
            }  
            break;          
        case '\n':
            i = 0;
            cursor_position.x = 0;
            cursor_position.y++;
            break;
        case '\t':
            cursor_position.y += (cursor_position.x + i) / 80;
            cursor_position.x = (cursor_position.x + i) % 80;                    
            update_cursor(cursor_position.x, cursor_position.y);
            i = 0;
            cursor_position.x += TAB_SPACE - cursor_position.x % TAB_SPACE - 1;        
            break;
        default:
            *(char *)(0xb8000 +(cursor_position.x + i + cursor_position.y * 80) * 2) = *ptr;
            i++;
            break;
        }     
    }

    va_end(list_ptr);
    memset(buffer, '\0', 12);
    cursor_position.y += (cursor_position.x + i) / 80;
    cursor_position.x = (cursor_position.x + i) % 80;  
    update_cursor(cursor_position.x, cursor_position.y);
}
```

Call example:

```
    printv("Starting PonchOS!\n");
    char str[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        str[i] = 'a' + i;
    }
    str[11] = '\0';
    
    printv("Testtesttesttesttest");
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, it prints fine before any memory access, but after that, it leaves those white spaces. Any ideas as to why this happens?

Edit:
Implementing @chqrlie 's changes, some issues have been fixed, although spacing problems persist.
Code:

```
printv("Starting PonchOS!\n");
printv("%c\n", 'C');
printv("%i", 128);
printv("%s", "string");
```

Output:
[image: Undesired spacing]

Comment: When you call the function recursively, you must abandon `list_ptr` on return — it is no longer usable (and using it leads to undefined behaviour).  You must call `va_end()` and either return or restart the traversal with a new call to `va_start()`.  In practice, that means you need to do something other than recurse, I think.

Comment: If the recursion is only to send `buffer` to the video hardware directly (the `default` case) why not make that its own function. It should be separate from a "high level" print formatting function anyway, as a basic function that writes a string to the video memory. BTW it's useless to `memset(buffer, '\0', 12);` at the end of the function - `buffer` isn't used any more and is about to go out of life.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `list_ptr` is a local variable, the recursive call creates a new frame, how should that affect the local `va_list`? can you quote the Standard to substantiate your statement regarding recursive var_arg functions?

Comment: @chqrlie — C11 [§7.16 Variable arguments `<stdarg.h>` ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16p3): _… If access to the varying arguments is desired, the called function shall declare an object (generally referred to as `ap` in this subclause) having type `va_list`. The object `ap` may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the `va_arg` macro with parameter `ap`, the value of `ap` in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to `ap`._ A recursive call is 'another function' in this case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm afraid I disagree: the recursive calls to `printv` do not take the `va_list` as an argument. `list_ptr` has automatic storage and is not modified outside the original instance of `printv` so your quote seems irrelevant. Calling `printv()` recursively poses other problems, but not this one.

Comment: @chqrlie — I must have misread the code.  I thought that the `list_ptr` was passed recursively, but closer study shows I misread or misunderstood the code.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but:  `char (*screen)[80] = (char (*)[80])0xb8000;`, then later `screen[cursor_position.x][cursor_position.y] = *ptr;`

Comment: @dbush: the screen has 2 bytes per position, the first for the character, the second for text attributes such as foreground and background colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your not updating the cursor variables consistently when calling `printv` recursively. Furthermore you would get undefined behavior for this call: `printv("%s", "%s")`.

You should split the function into a high level one that handles the formatting and a low level one that draws a string to the screen.

Here is a modified version:

```
void putstr(const char *str, size_t n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        unsigned int tmp_cursor = get_cursor_position();
        int x = (unsigned short)(tmp_cursor >> 16);
        int y = (unsigned short)tmp_cursor;
        size_t i;
    
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            switch (str[i]) {
            case '\n':
                y += x / 80 + 1;
                x = 0;
                break;
            case '\r':
                y += x / 80;
                x = 0;
                break;
            case '\t':
                x = (x + TAB_SPACE) / TAB_SPACE * TAB_SPACE;        
                y += x / 80;
                x %= 80;
                break;
            default:
                *(char *)(0xb8000 + (y * 80 + x) * 2) = str[i];
                x++;
                break;
            }
        }     
        update_cursor(x, y);
    }
}

void printv(const char *str, ...) {
    char buffer[32];
    char *p;
    const char *ptr;
    va_list list_ptr;
    va_start(list_ptr, str);

    for (ptr = str; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++) {
        if (*ptr == '%' && ptr[1] != '\0') {
            putstr(str, ptr - str);
            str = ptr;
            ptr++;
            switch (*ptr) {
            case 'c':
                buffer[0] = (char)va_arg(list_ptr, int);
                putstr(buffer, 1);
                str += 2; // skip the format
                break;
            case 's':
                p = va_arg(list_ptr, char *);
                putstr(p, strlen(p));
                str += 2; // skip the format
                break;
            case 'i':
            case 'd':                
                int_to_str(va_arg(list_ptr, int), buffer, 10);
                putstr(buffer, strlen(buffer));
                str += 2; // skip the format
                break;
            case '%':
                str += 1; // skip the initial %
                break;
            }
        }     
    }
    putstr(str, ptr - str);
    va_end(list_ptr);
}
```

Comment: I copied your code (with a few minor modifications), and it works fine for printing only strings, but as soon as I try to print a variable,  the foor loop inside `putstr` goes over the desired length, printing the content of other memory locations.

Comment: yeah, I mean anything that uses the % (%s, %c, etc). Even chars will just keep printing

Comment: I've applied these changes but the output is still buggy. `printv("%c", 'C');` will output something along the lines of: 8 white spaces _C 589800_ some other string in memory.
`%i` and `%s` give similar outputs.

Comment: I figured out why this was happening. If nothing was to be printed after a formatted variable (e.g.: just using `printv("%c", 'C')`), there are no checks to ensure that `str = ptr += 2;` isn't itself the end of the string.
That solved the extra numbers and strings being printed, but the white space problem remains.

Comment: while your answer has ben **a lot** of help with other problems in the code, the undesired spacing bug persists, that's why I haven't mark your answer as accepted

Comment: @AlfonsoCastillo: I have further simplified the code, but I do not understand why the spacing bug persists. I am not sure if `get_cursor_position()` and `update_cursor()` behave as expected. Can you append an update to the question with more test cases and the corresponding screenshot?

Comment: I don't think `get_cursor_position()` and `update_cursor()` are the problem, but I'll look into that as well

Comment: I don't know where the problem comes from. Where does the text `This tex        t was in        putted b        y the k        eyboard` come from? Funny 8 spaces every 8 characters... Can you post the cursor handling routines source code?

Comment: you were right, the cursor handling routines were at fault for the spacing problem, should've checked that from the beginning.